# |A| = n, |B| = m, show that |AxB|=n*m. n,m ∈ ℕ

Tags: logic

|A| = n, |B| = m

I have to show that

|AxB|=n*m

Giving the variables values, the equation can be shown, but I have to show that it is valid for all n and m's ∈ ℕ

It looks like an induction but we have two variables and I do not know how to show that for two variables via induction. Can anyone help?

Comment: There is no need to use induction

Comment: You can fix n and use induction on m. Since n is arbitrary your statement follows. It's actually proven using the basic multiplication principle from combinatorics

Comment: @Dude How that "using basic multimplication principle from combinatorics"?

Comment: Let (a, b) be an element of A×B, with a  in A and b in B. There are n ways to choose a, i.e. the first element of the couple. Similarly there are m ways to choose b. Hence m•n ways to choose (a, b), and this is the cardinality of A×B

Comment: @Dude Giving an answer I could mark it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let's take a look at $A\times B$.

We know that $A \times B = \{(a,b): a \in A, b\in B\}$.

So, let's take a look at all such ordered pairs $(a,b)$:

We note that since $|A| = n$, the value of $a$ can be one of exactly $n$ choices. So, we have the following $n$ number of ordered pairs:

$(1,b), (2,b), (3,b), ..., (n,b)$

However, we also have $m$ possible values for $b$, so we can make the following array:

$(1,1), (2,1), (3,1), ..., (n,1)$ $\qquad$ This row contains all ordered pairs where $b = 1$

$(1,2), (2,2), (3,2), ..., (n,2)$ $\qquad$ This row contains all ordered pairs where $b = 2$

$(1,3), (2,3), (3,3), ..., (n,3)$ $\qquad$  This row contains all ordered pairs where $b = 3$

$...$

$(1,m), (2,m), (3,m), ..., (n,m)$ $\qquad$This row contains all ordered pairs where $b = m$

If we take a look at all the possible choices of ordered pairs $(a,b)$, we see that we have a rectangular array with $n$ columns and $m$ rows. Hence, the total number of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ that we have is simply $mn$.

So $|A\times B| = mn$.